# Google Spreadsheets‎で文字が含まれていたら真偽値を返して欲しい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

`=FINDB(F4,"月火水木金")`
とセルに書いた場合、`F4`が`木`など含まれている文字なら`数値`が返ってくるのですが、
`土`など含まれていない文字列だとError扱いになってしまいます。
真偽値を返してほしいです（別の関数を使用してもよいです）。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

`=IFERROR(FINDB(F4,"月火水木金"),false)`で`ERROR`のとき`false`を返せました。